# Moving an SCNNode relative to the root node

Tags: scenekit

I’m learning SceneKit by writing a game where you’re flying through an asteroid field dodging objects. Initially, I did this by moving/rotating the camera, but I realized that at some point I’d run out of coordinate space and it’s probably better to move all of the objects toward the camera (and dispose of them when I’ve “passed” them).

But I can’t seem to get them to move. My original code that moved the camera looked like this:

```
[cameraNode setTransform:CATransform3DTranslate(cameraNode.transform, 0.f, 0.f, -2.f)];
```

I thought I could do something similar with each asteroid node:

```
[asteroidNode setTransform:CATransform3DTranslate(cameraNode.transform, 0.f, 0.f, 2.f)];
```

but they don’t move. If I add a basic animation:

```
CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.z"];
anim.byValue = @10;
anim.duration = 1.0;
[asteroidNode addAnimation:anim forKey:@"move forward"];
```

the asteroids move but predictably snap back to their original location when it’s done.

This feels like a rookie mistake but I can’t find anything addressing this problem online. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

moving the cameraNode the way you do it should work but make sure "cameraNode" is your current pointOfView or it will have no effect (check that scnView.pointOfView == cameraNode).

If you want to move the nodes instead you should translate "node.transform" (not "cameraNode.transform"). But Actually it's simpler to just do:

node.position = SCNVector3Make(node.position.x, node.position.y, node.position.z+2.0);

Also make sure there is no animation or physics running on these nodes that could override your changes.

Comment: Thank you, Toyos! The "cameraNode.transform" was just a copy and paste error in this post, but the asteroids were rotating and it looks like that was messing up the transformation. When I disable the rotation everything works as expected. Now it's just a matter of getting the rotation and the translation to work together based on whether the ship is moving or not, which I can hopefully figure out... And thanks for the tip on simplifying the code, too!

Comment: I didn't know the pointOfView property existed, thank you so much.